# In hibernate tracking the data that saving in Database

Tags: java, hibernate, encryption

I am working on encrypting and decrypting of savable data of my application. For that i need to know the strings that saving in my database(I need them exactly just before saving into DB).

How to track that data while before saving ?? any help ??

thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the help of Data Access Object design pattern. where u can track data before going to save by implementing your custom function

Comment: can you give me an example...

Comment: public class CustomerDAO  {
  
  public CloudscapeCustomerDAO() {
    // initialization 
  }

    public int insertCustomer(...) {
    //call ur custom code here before calling session.save();

  }
  
  
}

Answer (score 1):

Hinernate supports the concept of [interceptors and events](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html). You can use the `public boolean onSave(...)`